# Enhancements of Bertrand's postulate?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Is there a smallest real number $a$ such that there exist a natural number $N$ so that:

$n>N\implies p_{n+1}\leq a\cdot p_n$?

I believe it can be proved that $n>7\implies p_{n+1}\leq \sqrt 2\cdot p_n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no smallest such $a$, but the infimum of the set of such $a$ is $1$. In other words, for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a prime between $n$ and $(1+\epsilon)n$ for all sufficiently large $n$. This follows from the prime number theorem.

As a concrete example, for all $n\ge25$, there is a prime between $n$ and $\frac 65 n$ (Nagura 1952)..

Answer (score 1):

Using the prime-number theorem:
$$\begin{array} {rll} & p_{n+1} &\le a \cdot p_n \\
 & { p_{n+1}\over p_{n}} &\le a \\
 \text{(asymptotically:)}&{ (n+1) \log(n+1)\over n \log(n)} &\le a  \\
& { (1+1/n) \over 1 } { \log(n+1)\over  \log(n)} &\le a  \\
& ( 1+1/n)\cdot (1+{ \log(1+1/n)\over  \log(n)}) &\le a  
\end{array}$$
and the lhs on the last expression can be made arbitrarily near to $1$ by increasing $n$  so also $a$ can be  taken arbitrarily small by using appropriate $n$

(However, that arguing/wording might be formally imprecise, I'm not much literate with *formally proving*; Hagen von Eitzen's arguing might be more correct)